# HoTT without Funext, Univalence

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, homotopy-type-theory

Are there any models of Martin-Löf's intensional type theory in which univalence or function extensionality fails?

In the [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), axioms like $\mathsf{LEM}_{\infty}$ (in Section 3.4) are proved to be inconsistent with univalence. I suppose that there might be some models in which univalence fails and such axioms hold, which is interesting.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. As far as I know, univalence is sort of the definition of what HoTT is..?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

“HoTT” isn’t generally currently considered as referring to a single specific formal system — it’s a similar situation to, say, “constructive mathematics”, for which there are various different more or less well-studied formal systems.

The core of most systems currently used for HoTT is Martin-Löf’s intensional type theory, **ITT**, usually also with funext.  This is agnostic on homotopical questions: it has both the simplicial set model, where univalence holds, and the good old-fashioned set model, where UIP holds (“uniqueness of identity proofs” — in HoTT terminology, the statement/scheme asserting that every type is a set), and (at least as long as you’re working with ZFC or similar as your background foundation) LEM∞ holds as well.  So in this case, LEM∞ certainly can hold — but it’s not what one would usually call a model of HoTT.

On the other hand, you might mean a stronger system — **ITT** augmented with some homotopical axioms, like univalence.  In this case, because of the results you mention, there can’t be any model where LEM∞ holds.

One reasonable in-between thing one might mean by “models of HoTT” would be: models of **ITT** in which UIP doesn’t hold, i.e. models which are “homotopically non-trivial”.  For this sense, the answer to your question is **no,** LEM∞ **can’t hold in such models,** since [Hedberg’s Theorem](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2012/03/30/a-direct-proof-of-hedbergs-theorem/) shows that LEM∞ implies UIP, so any model of **ITT** + LEM∞ is homotopically trivial.

Comment: However, there are also models in which UIP and univalence, and even function extensionality, *all* fail.  For instance, the projective model in Z/2-groupoids in http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04083 .  A less esoteric possibility is the strict $\infty$-groupoid model in http://mawarren.net/papers/crmp1295.pdf, though I don't recall whether it's been checked that univalence fails there (though IIRC we don't expect it to).

Comment: Thanks, Peter and @mike-shulman. I mean models of **ITT** without univalence or funext, and "good old-fashioned set model" in Peter's answer and ones in Mike's answer are what I want. I shouldn't have used the word "HoTT".